# How to dismiss controller and then switch tabs

Tags: swift

I have two main VC that are in a tab bar controller. On the first VC when you tap a button you are taken to another VC (not the 2nd tab bar VC) and when you tap the finish button I want to go to the 2nd tab bar vc.

Normally I would just perform segue ... but when I do that it removes the tab bar at the bottom. So, I am now just dismissing and going back to the original VC, but I would really like to go to the 2nd tab bar vc so I tried this

```
dismiss(animated: true) { 
  self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
}
```

I saw the self.tabBar... on another SO post, but I can't seem to find where I set the Index...ive tried 1 in case it just automatically starts from 0, and Ive tried 2 in case it starts from 1

Am I close or is there a better way of achieving what I want?

**Summary**

To summarize clearly. I have 3 View Controllers. 1 and 3 are in a Tab Bar Controller. VC 2 is NOT in the TBC. To get to VC 2 there is a button on VC 1. When the user is finished on VC 2 he/she taps a button. Instead of just dismissing back to VC 1 I want to go to VC 3, but when I perform segue it goes to VC 3 but removes the Tab Bar

Comment: You have provided not enough information.First of all: "taken to another VC" - presented modally of pushed to navigation stack? When you say "dismiss" and it means modal presentation. What is the way you present "another VC"? firstVC.present(...) or firstVC.tabController.present(...)? if it is firstVC.present then try switching to firstVC.tabController.present. I think you should find a solution why is the tab bar was removed. I bet it shouldn't

Comment: In order to get correct answer, please provide more details.

Q1. How do you set your rootVC?

Q2. How do you add UITabbarVC?

Q3. How do you add VC1,VC2 and VC3?

Comment: If the `dismiss` code is in VC 2, then the completion handler does nothing, because VC 2 is not in a `UITabBarController` and therefore `self.tabBarController` is `nil`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure you have a `UINavigationController` as the first ViewController. Then you have access to the tabBarController and can then switch the tabs:

[image: view controllers]

```
// if vc was pushed
@IBAction func onFinish(_ sender: Any) {
    // store tabBarController for later use
    let tabBarController = self.tabBarController

    // pop to root vc (green one)
    _ = self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)

    // switch to 2nd tab (red vc)
    tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
}
```

---

```
// if vc was presented modally
@IBAction func onFinish(_ sender: Any) {
    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

    if let tabBarController = self.presentingViewController as? UITabBarController {
        tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
    }
}
```

---

```
// if vc was presented modally + switching tab in completion block
@IBAction func onFinish(_ sender: Any) {
    if let tabBarController = self.presentingViewController as? UITabBarController {
        self.dismiss(animated: true) {
            tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try when I get back home

Comment: SO says I have to wait 16 hours to award your bounty...I will do it then, I was trying to do that type of code inside the completion block instead of doing after the dismiss. Thank you

Comment: @RubberDucky4444 switching the tab in the completion block also works. but you have to get the presentingViewController from self first. (after the dismissal self.presentingViewController would be nil)

Comment: @d.felber I use your third solution. I have a question is that why presentingViewController is UITabBarController but not UINavigationController. So Is there some way to get NavigationController embed in TabController if I also want to change the label text in NavigationController's topViewController?

Answer (score 0):

Indexes will most likely always start from 0 in any language you use.

As for the tab bar you are calling `self` on the view controller presented not on the view controller that it is dismissing to.  You should be able to do

```
self.window?.rootViewController.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
```

in order to accomplish this.  This might not work based on the setup of your VCs so you might have to play with it.

Comment: @RubberDucky4444 try `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow.rootViewController` if that doesn't work then you can also try loading the tab controller from your storyboard using `storyBoard.instantiateViewController()`

Answer (score 0):

You can move to specific index before dismiss view controller.

```
func moveToVC() {
        if let mainNavVC = self.presentingViewController as? UINavigationController {
            if mainNavVC.viewControllers.count > 0 {
                if let tabbarVC = mainNavVC.viewControllers.first as? TabBarViewController {
                    tabbarVC.selectedIndex = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
```